# Rendering javascript page for a json request in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using rails 3.1. I send in my ajax request as json object but in my controller inside my respond_to function i would like to render a rjs file. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rjs files are no longer part of Rails 3. There are however .js.erb files. Not having developed in Rails 2 I'm not totally sure what .rjs files used to contain so that I cannot answer.

Comment: Hmmm, in that case how would i call my partials within my js.erb files? is it possible to do that?

Comment: Yeah it is through <%= render 'partial' %>, you might want to wrap it with escape_javascript